# Rearrangement of Matrix Equation

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have a matrix equation

**x = kAx + y**

Where x is a vector, c is a vector, k is a scalar, and A is a matrix. I'm looking to rearrange it into a form

**Bx = z**

I know that my vector x will be in the same form, and that matrix A and vector y will be altered through rearrangement.

I know I have to use the inverse matrix in order to do so. It's wrong, in part only because division isn't a matrix operation, but here's what I have so far.

**Ix = I (kAx + y)**

**Ix = IkAx + Iy**

**Ix - IkAx = Iy**

**Ax(A^1 - Ik) = Iy**

**Ax = Iy / (A^-1 - Ik)**

**Ax = y / (A^-1 - k)**

I'm sorry I don't know how to format the math properly. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $X=kAX+Y$ so
$$A^{-1}X=kX+A^{-1}Y$$ then $BX=Z$ where $Z=A^{-1}Y$ and $B=(A^{-1}-kI)$